# Update nested fields in Mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

I have a Json for vendor:

```
{
   "id": 1, 
   "contact": {
       "address": "abc",
       "phone": "123456"
   }
}
```

If the update is *{"contact": {"address":"xyz"}}*, the address should be updated to *xyz*, and phone is still there, i.e. not deleted.

I know **$set** and **dot** notation (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/), for example, *{$set: {"contact.address":"xyz"}}*, can do this.

However, what I am trying to do is to come out with a generic solution in the sense that it can be applied to models with nested depth larger than 2. In other words, given the *update* in json form, the solution should ONLY update the fields specified in the *update* and leave other fields intact.

Comment: You need to generate a set of dot-notation field updates from the input JSON object.

Comment: How to make it in code that can be applied to all models.

Comment: @LuongBaLinh I'm not clear... whats not general enough about dot notation? Why do you think you are unable to go to an arbitrary depth?

Comment: If there's more than one field, each at a different depth, perhaps it might be better to assign the record to a variable, use dot notation to update the fields and call a db.collection.update().